# fabricjs export specific elements to SVG

Tags: fabricjs

Is it possible to specify particular layers/elements when using toSVG ?

I have a canvas with both an overlayImage and a backgroundImage, and I would like to extract the svg for every other element added to the canvas.

So far my only solution was to set opacity to 0 for both background image and overlay image then apply toSVG, and finally restore opacity to 1, but I assume there probably is an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set "excludeFromExport" property on overlayImage and backgroundImage for exclude from toSVG, toJSON

[excludeFromExport](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#excludeFromExport)